# No Module named numpy; but it already installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, numpy-ndarray, numpy-ufunc

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/acer/Downloads/len.py", line 1, in 
    from numpy import log
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'**

what i have to do?? please help me

Comment: did you check using pip freeze ?

Answer (score 0):

You said you installed it, how did you proceed ? I would suggest to run

```
pip install numpy
```

from the terminal.